# UserContext in CrossCutting

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working in a project where we have an interface called `IUserContext` in the CrossCutting which decorates an User entity in our Domain.

This `IUserContext` represents the current logged in user.

**First of all:** Does `IUserContext` belong to CrossCutting at all?

The User entity looks something like that:

```
public sealed class User : Entity, IUserContext
{
    public ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

This was done because they want to inject the `IUserContext` wherever they need.

Ok!

Now I have the task to create a Permission service. In this service I need to inject `IUserContext` as well, so I can check permissions for the current logged in user. My thought:

```
    private readonly IUserContext _userContext;

    public PermissionService(IUserContext userContext)
    {
        _userContext = userContext;
    }

    public bool HasPermission(string permission)
    {
        return _userContext.Permissions.Any(x => x.Name == permission);
    }
```

**The problem:** The User entity has the `ICollection<Permission>` where Permission is an entity itself and I can not create for the `IUserContext` a property of `ICollection<Permission>` because CrossCutting has no knowledge about the Domain which contains the entity Permission, what is correct.

Would be the correct approach to remove `IUserContext` from CrossCutting and placing it into the Domain? If so, what would I need to also have the current logged in User in other layers where the domain is not visible (UI Layer for example) ?

Comment: I would not mix that. Try using IIdentity and IPrincipal interfaces of the .NET Framework to represent the current user.

Comment: and add the Permissions as Claims?

Comment: I'll try refactoring this to IPrincipal with roles